# Как передавать ссылку на загрузку файла?

Tags: php, html, url, yandex-disk

**Немного поточнее:**
Имеется Яндекс.Диск, в котором по папкам раскиданы файлы. Есть сервис, который умеет через Яндекс.Диск api получать ссылку для загрузки файла. Вот по этой ссылке пользователь должен скачать файл.
**Как отдаются файлы на данный момент**:

```
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: filename="'.$fileName.'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    readfile($link);
    exit;
```

**Проблема**: у некоторых файлов длинное имя кириллицей и ссылка для загрузки получается очень длинной (может быть > 700 символов) и по какой то причине readfile() с такой ссылкой мне отдает файл 0 байт. Это я выяснил методом тыка. С ссылками ~400-500 символов все нормально.
**Что я пробовал делать**:
1)возвращать пользователю Header('Location: ссылка') и window.location.replace("ссылка");. В обоих случаях мне возвращалась ошибка 404. Но если в строке браузера выделить ссылку и снова перейти по ней, то файл загружается, но пользователям так не удобно...
2) `readfile(urldecode($link))` - не помогло.

Пример ссылки (временная). По ней readfile не загрузит файл.
https://downloader.disk.yandex.ru/disk/52c3337c365d9044817e92ed2703cc8a4a496f796d8980b3275b3bc7017deb16/5f808e47/EwE7dCJGCpeSA5HvX_gAhD92c7nRGPL5t8Rdyf2UQ0nox42CuKvGq1KO4wRbIyWN8OQP1FUGENiZzW2EdGrI2Q%3D%3D?uid=1096029541&filename=%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%E2%84%9612345678_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82_%E2%84%961234567_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B_%E2%84%961233456_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8.zip&disposition=attachment&hash=&limit=0&content_type=application%2Fzip&owner_uid=1096029541&fsize=255&hid=d009b8d7098c222298f285ec79dcafa9&media_type=compressed&tknv=v2&etag=8cea810e7ab846f2545e72ad5c92a11e

Пример рабочей (короткой) ссылки:
https://downloader.disk.yandex.ru/disk/6588a657572f436808dbb49624bcc8dff19a49d2f291cdd0a0af3d576231a2da/5f808f03/fKqInKw3d7bLFOeFnMGnhCeKJj9YyFgvY444Pl-jL4npo-h8eLjZ0R98ilOUCa9RoU-mwY58ezrNZrtNJeerOrCJ5Wf9lyUTsKmOUxllosGr8npumZHI4midPdWhecNq?uid=1096029541&filename=sc.txt&disposition=attachment&hash=&limit=0&content_type=text%2Fplain&owner_uid=1096029541&fsize=66&hid=6654bced876356c2aef0f3728330cf74&media_type=document&tknv=v2&etag=23410687fffe0403b4e49000ce0babaa

UPD файл с кодом:

```
<?php
$yadToken = 'secret';
function curl($url, $data, $headers, $method = 'POST', $retryCount = 7, $lastResponse = NULL) {
    if ($retryCount > 1) {
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);
        //check first num in http code
        if(substr($httpcode, 0, 1) == 2)
            return $response;
         else
            usleep(125000);
            return curl($url, $data, $headers, $method, --$retryCount, $response);
    } else {
        return $lastResponse;
    }
}
// пример пути: /dir1/dir2/my_file.txt
function getLinkToDownloadFile($path) {
    $url = 'https://cloud-api.yandex.net/v1/disk/resources/download?path='.$path;
    $headers = array(
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Authorization: OAuth '.$GLOBALS['yadToken']
    );
    $resp = curl($url, array(), $headers, 'GET');
    return json_decode($resp, true)['href'];
}
if(isset($_GET['path']))
{
    $path = $_GET['path'];
    $link = getLinkToDownloadFile($path);
    $slashIndex = strripos($path, '/');
    $fileName = substr($path, slashIndex + 1);
   
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: filename="'.$fileName.'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    readfile($link);
    exit;
} else {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.location = "/"</script>';
}
?>
```

**UPD:**
Если в `echo file_get_contents()` поместить эту длинную ссылку, то ничего не выводит, в других случаях текст/мусор.

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста или меня на работе съедят =( Я на скале пишу и не знаю почему это на меня скинули...

Comment: Как вариант, вызвать диалог через [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js). Можно попробовать совсем костылить: создаём <a> и кликаем по нему [codepen.io/loonybtard/pen/BazyYpp](https://codepen.io/loonybtard/pen/BazyYpp).

Comment: Пробовал, получал то же самое, 404, пункт "Что я пробовал делать" 1).

Comment: Таки нет. В первом пункте вы пишете про `window.location.replace` что всё же отличается. Было бы неплохо добавить пример ссылки, это упростит нахождение решения

Comment: Возможно я не понимаю чего-то но [такой код](https://pastebin.com/YMPYLuBM) даёт мне скачать файл ([пример](https://sheet.idleness.ru/long_link.php)). C [readfile](https://pastebin.com/ZGqSj1vp) тоже всё работает ([пример](https://sheet.idleness.ru/long_link_readfile.php))

Comment: Хмм, я зашел в тупик. Я тоже попробовал [твой код](https://pastebin.com/YMPYLuBM) закинуть в корень сайта с длинной ссылкой и файл загружается...

Comment: А на момент `readfile` ссылка точно валидная? Просто если [на неё навесить `urlencode`](https://pastebin.com/VbvVcQfg) то я получаю ровно то поведение что указано в вопросе (404, но если выделить и кликнуть то работает). Понимаю перекликается со вторым пунктом "Что я пробовал делать" но может стоит проверить ещё раз? Ссылку точно не обрабатывает какой-нибудь `htmlentities`?

Comment: Но я же как то могу скачивать файлы с короткими названиями. Дополнил описание.

Comment: + если убрать все header, readfile и сделать просто echo $link;, то печатается валидная ссылка, по ней все грузится.

Comment: `...пробовал ... возвращать пользователю Header('Location: ссылка') и window.location.replace("ссылка"). В обоих случаях мне возвращалась ошибка 404.` Очень похоже, что загрузка блокируется из-за `HTTP referer`. А когда `referer` нет, то все качается.